# what are the events(hooks) in joomla 1.7 to add plugins code

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

what are the events(hooks) in joomla 1.7 to add plugins ?

I have been developing some joomla plugins, I would like to know how many events(like onContentBeforeDisplay) we have in joomla to include plugin codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't vouch for how comprehensive or up-to-date this is, but here is the link to [Joomla's wiki documentation on plugin events](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events)

Hope that helps. Perhaps the best advice is to look within the /plugins/ folder and its sub-folders. There are (or used to be??) example.php plugins contained therein.